# Send an AJAX request and pass JSON data as a response in html

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, jqgrid

**Javascript**

```
$.post( 
        SITE_URL+"mycontroller/myAction",
        {
        start_date : '01-JUL-15',
        end_date : '31-JUL-15',
        resource_ids : '100,200',
        project_id : 10
        },
        function(json){
        alert(json);
}, 'json');



    var selResId = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
    resourceLength = selResId.length;

    if (resourceLength > 0) {

    var names = [];
    var j=1;
    for (var i=0, il=selResId.length; i < il; i++) {

    var name = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getCell', selResId[i], 'USER_NAME');

    $('#addr'+j).html("<td style='text-align:center;'>"+name+"</td><td style='text-align:center;'>"+skill+"</td><td>"+status+"</td>");
    $('#resource_table').append('<tr id="addr'+(j+1)+'"></tr>');
        j++;
        }
}
```

**HTML where data will be appended**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="resource_table">
<tbody>
   <tr id='addr1'></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**PHP Data output**

```
$result = 
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [USER_ID] => 100
                [USER_NAME] => User One
                [SKILL] => Application Software
                [STATUS] => Onsite
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [USER_ID] => 200
                [USER_NAME] => User Two
                [SKILL] => Application Software
                [STATUS] => Offshore
            )

    );
```

Further

```
foreach ($result as $final_result){ 
    $skills[] = $final_result['SKILL_NAME'];
    $status[] = $final_result['ACTUAL_HOURS'];
}

    $result_arr = array();
    $result_arr['skills'] = $skills;
    $result_arr['status'] = $status;
    echo json_encode($result_arr);exit;
```

**Printing `$result_arr`**

```
Array
(
    [skills] => Array
        (
            [0] => Application Software
            [1] => Application Software
        )

    [status] => Array
        (
            [0] => Onsite
            [1] => Offshore
        )

)
```

I am able to append User Name dynamically using jqgrid code `var name = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getCell', selResId[i], 'USER_NAME');`, but how can I send PHP data as response to dynamically display `Skill` and `Status` according to relevant user as shown in below image.

[image]

Comment: what exactly do u mean by `but how can I process PHP data` ? you want to pass the skills to php script ?

Comment: Send data as response and pass it in html to display skills and status.

Comment: Above json is what you have got from `$.post` ? if yes, then you can just set  the skill and status with the value returned from `Json` response inside for loop.

Comment: @dreamweiver and how to go about it ? How to pass PHP output back to success function and set the value in html as done for user_name. Pls see   updated question

Comment: for that you need to just output the data which u need to send it to client using `echo`. i have posted the detail info abt the same below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store the json response received from server script in `response` & then loop around the json `response` to get the corresponding data(skill & status).

Since you have the code to update the DOM with related values already,rest of the code should work as intended.

**JS Code:**

```
 var response;
 $.post( 
    SITE_URL+"mycontroller/myAction",
    {
    start_date : '01-JUL-15',
    end_date : '31-JUL-15',
    resource_ids : '100,200',
    project_id : 10
    },
    function(json){
       processResponse(json);
}, 'json');

....
....
function processResponse(response) {
  var selResId = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
  resourceLength = selResId.length;

  if (resourceLength > 0) {
   var names = [];
   var j=1;
   for (var i=0, il=selResId.length; i < il; i++) {
     var skill = response[i].skill;
     var status = response[i].status;
     var name = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getCell', selResId[i], 'USER_NAME');

     $('#addr'+j).html("<td style='text-align:center;'>"+name+"</td><td style='text-align:center;'>"+skill+"</td><td>"+status+"</td>");
     $('#resource_table').append('<tr id="addr'+(j+1)+'"></tr>');
     j++;
   } 
}
```

At the same time, you need to `echo` the response data which you need to send it to client application eg., `$.post`.

**PHP SCRIPT**

```
//response should contain the above json
<?php echo response; ?>
```

Comment: I have updated my PHP code a bit for your understanding on how I'am passing the data. Could you please elaborate on json data to be passed in order to work with your above snippet. Also using above it says, `TypeError: response is undefined var skill = response[i].skill;` OR Should I change my PHP data ?

Comment: I have changed the code a bit, i beleive now it should work fine.

Comment: For my above PHP code, I implemented as per your snippet and it says `TypeError: response[i] is undefined` Am I making some mistake in passing PHP data in correct array format ? My json_encode response `{"skills":["Application Software","Application Software"],"site_status":["Onsite","Offshore"]}`

Comment: `console.log(response)` output in function `processResponse` `[Object { USER_ID="100",  SKILL="Application Software",  SITE_STATUS="Offshore"}, Object { USER_ID="200",  SKILL="Application Software",  SITE_STATUS="Offshore"}]` AND console.log(response[i].skill); is undefined

Comment: ahhh, try using `var skill = response[i].SKILL;
     var status = response[i].STATUS;` i thought it was lowercase from your question,because json response is case-sensitive.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: if you have found the solution can we close this question

Comment: my bad for considering json response case-insensitive. Appreciate your help for this issue..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi this one will helpful to you .


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="click me to load" onclick="getAjaxRes();" />
<script>
function getAjaxRes()
{
    var get_tr="";
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"js_ex.php",
        data:{my_data:"sometning_ip"},
        success:function(res_data)
        {
            console.log("data_result="+res_data);
            if(res_data!='')
            {
                var geting_res=JSON.parse(res_data);
                var get_tr="<tr><th>USER_ID</th><th>USER NAME</th><th>SKILL</th><th>STATUS</th>";
                for(var x in geting_res)
                {
                    var user_id=geting_res[x].USER_ID;
                    var user_name=geting_res[x].USER_NAME;
                    var user_skill=geting_res[x].SKILL;
                    var user_status=geting_res[x].STATUS;
                    get_tr+="<tr><td>"+user_id+"</td><td>"+user_name+"</td><td>"+user_skill+"</td><td>"+user_status+"</td><tr>";  
                }
                console.log(get_tr);
                $('#table_show').html(get_tr);
            }
        }
    });

}
</script>
<style>
th,td { border: 1px solid #2e2e2e; }
</style>
<table id="table_show"></table>

Ajax File Name js_ex.php , ajax json result is below

<?php
$my_array=array(array("USER_ID"=>100,"USER_NAME"=>"Varun","SKILL"=>"Application Software","STATUS"=>"Onsite"),array("USER_ID"=>200,"USER_NAME"=>"Sarvanan","SKILL"=>"Testing Software","STATUS"=>"Offshore"));
echo json_encode($my_array);
?>
```